# Which Thread is Sleeping in this code? Main Thread or t1 thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

Generally Main thread starts first and then user threads starts, but in below code I am unable to figure out that main thread will sleep or t1 thread.

**MessageGenerator.java**

```
public class MessageGenerator implements Runnable {
    String msg;
    public MessageGenerator(String msg) {
        super();
        this.msg = msg;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Running");
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
}
```

**MainClass.java**

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Thread t1=new Thread(new MessageGenerator("Hello"));
        t1.sleep(5000); //Confused here
        t1.start();
        Thread t2=new Thread(new MessageGenerator("Hi"));
        t2.start();
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" Running");
    }
}
```

please reply

Comment: `t1` has not even been started, how can it be asleep?

Answer (score 9):

[`Thread.sleep(long millis)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-) is a `static` method that lets the **current thread** (which is, the thread that this method is being called from) sleep for the specified number of milliseconds.

In the example you gave, the main thread will sleep for 5 seconds - **not** the thread that `t1` refers to.

The code is misleading, because you are calling a `static` method on an instance.

Comment: just wondering.. can we instruct t1 to sleep from main thread somehow?

Comment: create a method in the `MessageGenerator` which contains `Thread.sleep` or see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797941/how-to-make-a-thread-sleep-for-specific-amount-of-time-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Sleep is a static method of Thread class, it should be called as `Thread.sleep(long millisec)`

Causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease execution) for the specified number of milliseconds, subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers. The thread does not lose ownership of any monitors.

Answer (score 0):

main thread will sleep ..for 5000 millisecond. 
sleep() is a static method that always references the current executing thread.so it call on main thread so main thread will sleep.